# I have an Oracle Stack trace file Python cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

My python application is dying, this oracle trace file is being generated. I am using cx_Oracle, how do I go about using this trace file to resolve this crash?

ora_18225_139690296567552.trc
kpedbg_dmp_stack()+360<-kpeDbgCrash()+192<-kpureq2()+3194<-OCIStmtPrepare2()+157<-Cursor_InternalPrepare()+298<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010<-0000000000EA3010

Comment: How and where did you install cx_Oracle? When is the crash happening? Is anything working at all (e.g. `import cx_Oracle`).

Comment: Yes, everything works but for some reason the application will just die with no python stack trace out of the blue and will leave this stack trace under the user directory. cx_Oracle is installed in the python site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/cx_Oracle.so

Comment: Here is another example of another trace that was generated today. trace/ora_5319_140531599382272.trc
kpedbg_dmp_stack()+360 <-kpeDbgCrash()+192 <-kpuexec()+4237 <-OCIStmtExecute()+39 <-Cursor_InternalExecute()+10 3<-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F5301 0 <-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F53010 <-0000000001F5301 0<-0000000001F53010

Comment: Which cx_Oracle command causes this? Can you even `import cx_Oracle`? Can you run a `connect` method? A `select` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an Oracle support contract?  If I would file an SR and upload the trace to Oracle and have them tell you what it is complaining about.  Those code calls are deep in their codebase from the looks of it.